# Is it possible to get current playing song data on Android? If yes How?

Tags: android, spotify, intentfilter

What I want to do is to get current playing song data. Song might be on spotify or any other music player. Actually I want to get data which transferred to phone hardware.

- Is it possible ?
- Is there a provided way to do it ?

I've tried, Broadcast Receiver with these filter but onReceived did not invoked. (tested with spotify android app)

```
    IntentFilter iF = new IntentFilter();
    iF.addCategory("ComponentInfo");
    iF.addCategory("com.spotify.mobile.android.service.SpotifyIntentService");
    iF.addCategory("com.spotify.mobile.android.service.SpotifyService");
    iF.addAction("com.spotify.mobile.android.ui.widget.SpotifyWidget");
    iF.addAction("ComponentInfo");
    iF.addAction("com.spotify");
    iF.addAction("com.spotify.mobile.android.service.SpotifyIntentService");
    iF.addAction("com.spotify.mobile.android.service.SpotifyService");
    iF.addAction("com.spotify.mobile.android.queuechanged");
    iF.addAction("com.spotify.mobile.android.metadatachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.android.music.playstatechanged");
    iF.addAction("com.android.music.playbackcomplete");
    iF.addAction("com.android.music.queuechanged");
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, iF);
```

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301113/how-to-get-info-of-what-user-listens-currently-in-spotify-app

Answer (score 0):

As of API 19, you can use [`RemoteControlClient.OnMetadataUpdateListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteControlClient.OnMetadataUpdateListener.html).

Comment: Is there any sample of how to use it?