# How to get info of what user listens currently in Spotify app

Tags: android, spotify, spotify-app

Can an Android app (runs on background and uses Spotify SDK) get info of which track the user listens currently at exact time in Spotify Android app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd be interested in the [Android Media Notifications](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/android-media-notifications/).

> If you are developing an Android application and want to know what is
>   happening in the Spotify app, you can subscribe to broadcast
>   notifications from it.