# Get name of track currently playing by Spotify user

Tags: javascript, html, spotify, webapi

Is there a way to get a users currently playing track and display it as a string on a web? Spotify knows what tracks are being played by a single user at the one time, is this possible? I have tried with no luck.

If not any suggestions to the best approach for something similar?

Comment: Show what you tried to get some help

Answer (score 1):

[Spotify's Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/) doesn't expose what a user is playing. If you're making an Android application, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301113/how-to-get-info-of-what-user-listens-currently-in-spotify-app/26303315#26303315).